# Adding php.exe directory to "PATH" so I can execute PHP on CMD isn't working! (WAMP)

Tags: php, cmd, execute

I tried executing a php file using "php nameOfFile.php" after navigating to its folder.

I got this error msg:

> php is not recognised as an internal or external command

I added this dir: `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12` which contain `php.exe` to PATH ("Environment Variables")

reopened CMD and I still get the same error msg.

googling this error doesn't help me because all do the same.

EDIT:

When navigating to the bin/php/php5.5.12 and running `php --version` 
I get the version output right.

When running the same on the main C:/ I get the first error back again "php is not recognised as an internal or external command"

Comment: When you just type `PATH`<enter> in the cmd window, do you see the php path in the output?

Comment: Yes I already checked this

Comment: But `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.exe -f nameOfFile.php` is working (or giving a different error message which implies that the step of locating the executable worked)? ( sorry, for the seemingly stupid questions - it's just such a basic thing that the problem "must" be rather simple ;-) )

Comment: Check and compare output from `where php` and `where /R C:\ php`

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer (yet), but unconvinient as a comment:
Can please run

```
<?php
foreach( explode(';', $_ENV['Path']) as $p ) {
    echo 
        false!==stripos($p, 'php') ? '>':' ',
        is_dir($p) ? '+':'-',
        file_exists($p.'\\php.exe') ? '#': ' ',
        $p, "\r\n"
    ;
}
```

from the console* and add the output to your question text?

The output should look like

```
 [...]
 + C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\
 + C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\
 + C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\
 + C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\
>+#c:\develop\php
```

*) the way you did it for your "EDIT:" section.